# Magento - how to show custom menu in top menu

Tags: magento

I need to show only first level categories and their products on top menu to replace Magento's default top menu.

For example categories and products should display like:

```
Category1
    Product name1
    Product name2
    Product name3
    Product name4
Category2
    Product name1
    Product name2
    Product name3
    Product name4
```

Menu html structure generating in block class and it will direct use in phtml.

Category tree structure is not required because of using only first level categories in store.

Any one has idea for this task?

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite navigation and top menu Magento blocks.

Following is example snippet.

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Abc_CustomMenu>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Abc_CustomMenu>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <custommenu>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Abc_CustomMenu</module>
          <frontName>custommenu</frontName>
        </args>
      </custommenu>
    </routers>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <custommenu>
          <file>custommenu.xml</file>
        </custommenu>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <custommenu>
        <class>Abc_CustomMenu_Helper</class>
      </custommenu>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <catalog>
        <rewrite>
          <navigation>Abc_CustomMenu_Block_Navigation</navigation>
        </rewrite>
      </catalog>
      <page>
        <rewrite>
          <html_topmenu>Abc_CustomMenu_Block_Topmenu</html_topmenu>
        </rewrite>
      </page>
      <custommenu>
        <class>Abc_CustomMenu_Block</class>
      </custommenu>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <default>
    <custommenu_sec1>
      <custommenu_grp1>
        <custommenu_enabled>1</custommenu_enabled>
        <custommenu_items_per_col>5</custommenu_items_per_col>
      </custommenu_grp1>
    </custommenu_sec1>
  </default>
</config>
```

**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <tabs>
    <Abc translate="label" module="custommenu">
      <label>Abc</label>
      <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    </Abc>
  </tabs>
  <sections>
    <custommenu_sec1  translate="label" module="custommenu">                    
      <label>Custom Menu</label>
      <tab>Abc</tab>
      <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
      <sort_order>310</sort_order>
      <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
      <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
      <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>            
      <groups>
        <custommenu_grp1 translate="label"> 
          <label>General</label>
          <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
          <sort_order>0</sort_order>
          <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
          <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
          <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
          <fields>
            <custommenu_enabled translate="label">
              <label>Enabled</label>
              <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
              <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
              <sort_order>0</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            </custommenu_enabled>                        
          </fields>
        </custommenu_grp1>
      </groups>
    </custommenu_sec1>
  </sections>
</config>
```

**custommenu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <default>
    <block type="custommenu/toggle"></block>            
  </default>
</layout>
```

**Toggle.php**

```
class Abc_CustomMenu_Block_Toggle extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('custommenu_sec1/custommenu_grp1/custommenu_enabled')) return;
        $layout = $this->getLayout();
        $topnav = $layout->getBlock('catalog.topnav');
        if (is_object($topnav)) {
            $topnav->setTemplate('custommenu/top.phtml');
            $head = $layout->getBlock('head');            
            $head->addItem('skin_js', 'js/custommenu/custommenu.js');
        }
    }
}
```

**top.phtml**

```
// your custom code here to print category and its products as menu
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')//or you can just add some attributes
    ->addAttributeToFilter('level', 2)//2 is actually the first level
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)//if you want only active categories
;
foreach($categories as $cat)
{
    //get products from $cat category
}
```

**Navigation.php**

```
class Abc_CustomMenu_Block_Navigation extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation
{

}
```

**Topmenu.php**

```
if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('custommenu_sec1/custommenu_grp1/custommenu_enabled')) {
    class Abc_CustomMenu_Block_Topmenu extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu {}
    return;
}

class Abc_CustomMenu_Block_Topmenu extends Abc_CustomMenu_Block_Navigation {}
```

Comment: How to set collection of menu (category and there products) ?

Comment: It will be in `top.phtml` file.

Comment: Default magento can not set product in menu items list and also it will all level categories, so how can set only first level categories and there product ?

Comment: In `top.phtml` file you need to write your own code to select only first level categories. And also their products one by one.

Comment: I updated `top.phtml` file code for selecting only first level categories.

Comment: Really good work. but i need to set menu HTML from block file. ignore collection loading in phtm file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85121/discussion-between-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd-and-user3793635).

Comment: Also maintenant all default class of categories and sub-categories (in my case it is product) like "level", "first", "last", "nav", "parent". how it is develope in custome menu code from block file.